# The relationship with _NSConcreteMallocBlock and NSMallocBlock?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I was digging what's a block really is, I find that in _Block_copy_internal(), we assign _NSConcreteMallocBlock to the result->isa, but _NSConcreteMallocBlock is a array with 32 counts void * elements, it confused me a lot, why define _NSConcreteMallocBlock to a array pointer?and how did the dyld link the _NSConcreteMallocBlock to the NSMallocBlock class?

Answer (score 1):

The declaring it as 32 pointers simply reserves space for the size of the class object they will put there later.

If you read the comment in https://opensource.apple.com/source/libclosure/libclosure-65/data.c

> These data areas are set up by Foundation to link in as real classes
>   post facto.

Foundation is closed-source so you cannot see how that works and what content they put into that space.

Answer (score 0):

thanks, I have understood this by disassembling CoreFoundation and Foundation Framework, found this code:

```
___CFMakeNSBlockClasses:

0000000000008029        leaq    0x4522b0(%rip), %rdi    ## literal pool for: “__NSStackBlock"
0000000000008030        callq   0x1d4858                ## symbol stub for: _objc_lookUpClass
0000000000008035        movq    0x46f07c(%rip), %rdx    ## literal pool symbol address: __NSConcreteStackBlock
000000000000803c        movq    %rdx, %rcx
000000000000803f        subq    $-0x80, %rcx
0000000000008043        leaq    0x4522a5(%rip), %rsi    ## literal pool for: "__NSStackBlock__"
000000000000804a        movq    %rax, %rdi
```

this assemble code corresponding to these OC code:

```
Class __NSStackBlock = _objc_lookUpClass(“__NSStackBlock”);
objc_initializeClassPair_internal(__NSStackBlock, “__NSStackBlock__”, &__NSConcreteStackBlock, &__NSConcreteStackBlock+0x80);
```